# How to hide all file extensions in subdirectories of a given folder?

Tags: macos, file-extensions

I know that I can open the file information dialogue (Get Info) for several files at once using ⌘⌥I and hide/unhide file extensions. How do I accomplish this for all files in a directory tree (including files in subfolders)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution using [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php):

I created a rule based on their posting *[How to get Hazel to go into subfolders](http://www.noodlesoft.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=470)*:

> If (…) *Kind is Folder*
>
> Do the following (…) *run rules on folder contents*

The next rule selects a certain set of files, e.g.

> If (…) *Kind is pdf*
>
> Do (…) *Run AppleScript embedded script*

The script is

```
tell application "Finder"
    set extension hidden of theFile to true
end tell
```

I defined more conditions more different file types, so it doesn’t work on *all* files as requested. With a limited number of different file types this should be no problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do this in Terminal with the `SetFile` command:

**To hide file extensions in a directory and all sub-directories:**

```
cd <path to directory>

find . -name "*.*" -exec SetFile -a -E '{}' \; | echo "hiding extensions"
```

(can change the second * to a particular extension type if you choose)

**To show file extensions in a directory and all sub-directories:**

```
cd <path to directory>

find . -name "*.*" -exec SetFile -a -e '{}' \; | echo "showing extensions"
```

Comment: I think you meant to say "-a e", not "-a -e".  "e" designates the extension you're changing.  It's the argument to "-a".

Comment: @Robert, It works the same with or without the `-`.

Comment: `SetFile` is deprecated since [Xcode 6](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016994-CH4-SW139).

Comment: @Jim that's correct, fixed now.

Answer (score -2):

See this page for a solution using Automator. Worked perfectly for me.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250660690

Comment: Please put the answer here. Answers should be understandable without links. But the link must be shown as well if copied from elsewhere or if it adds extra information